# How do I tag a document if a word is not present in it?

Tags: r, text-mining

I am performing text mining on text data having 2500 documents and looking for a specific word in the document.

I want to tag the document if a word say 'laceration' is not present in it and get the output as list of documents not having that word. And would also like to save the output in a text file.

I am using the following code

```
library(qdapRegex)

grab2 <- rm_(pattern=S("@around_", 1, "laceration", 1), extract=TRUE)

grab2(l$Text)
```

Sample output I am getting

```
[[2164]]
[1] NA

[[2165]]
[1] NA

[[2166]]
[1] "laceration"

[[2167]]
[1] NA

[[2168]]
[1] NA
```

I want the code which will return only the documents without the word 'laceration'. And want to write the output in a file.

Comment: Probably, you should be using a command line tool or perl. R isn't designed for efficiently parsing a bunch of files on disk.

Comment: If you know how to "tag" (whatever that means) a "document" (whatever that means: file or named in some formatted text bibliography) that has  "dance" in it, then assuming the 2500 "documents" can be listed by name in a vector, you should be able to use `setdiff` or `!(docs %in% hits)` to get the set difference.

Comment: As far as I know, `rm_` and `S` are not functions in vanilla R. If you're using a package, you should mention it and add it to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could do this in R, it would be much more efficient to do this at the command line (using a Linux-like OS or CygWin if on Windows):

```
grep -v "\blaceration\b" *.txt >ListOfNoLac
```

In R, you could do this:

```
fileList <- list.files(".", "\\.txt$")
hasLac <- sapply(fileList, function(x) length(grep("\\blaceration\\b", readLines(x))) > 0)
fileList[!hasLac]
```